# How do you access font everywhere in React pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

React pdf seems to handle font strangely. For example

I'm doing this:

```
Font.register({
  family: "Roboto",
  fonts: [
    {
      src: "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Me5WZLCzYlKw.ttf",
    },
    {
      src: "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlvAx05IsDqlA.ttf",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
  ],
})
```

when I access like so:

```
<View fixed style={{fontFamily: "Roboto"}}>
  // other content
</View>
```

it's fine but when I need to access it here:

```
      <Text
        render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) => (
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 8,
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              fontWeight: "bold",
            }}
          >{pageNumber}</Text>
        )}

      />
```

it says `Could not resolve font for Roboto, fontWeight bold`

why is this? and how do I apply this font and weight to this text element? Just for clarity it doesn't seem to cascade down either or work with just `fontWeight: bold`